# Enumerating Certificates Issue (X509Certificate2)

Tags: c#

I am attempting to enumerate certificate stores on my server and get information about each certificate. The code works correctly except it is missing all certificates found in the "Intermediate Certification Authorities" store.

```
string[] stores = new string[] { "AddressBook", "AuthRoot", "CertificateAuthority",     "Disallowed", "My", "Root", "TrustedPeople", "TrustedPublisher" };
           for (int x = 0; x < stores.Length; x++)
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store(stores[x],StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
                {
                          //handle certificates
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Is the store.Certificates collection empty for the "Intermediate Certification Authorities"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work, for some reason for every store except "CertificateAuthority" you can pass the name as I did in my original code (stores[x]). For "CertificateAuthority" I had to explicitly pass "Store.CertificateAuthority". I feel like this is a bug in the X509Store class.

```
//Old Code
string[] stores = new string[] { "AddressBook", "AuthRoot", "CertificateAuthority" "Disallowed", "My", "Root", "TrustedPeople", "TrustedPublisher" };
X509Store store = new X509Store(stores[x],StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

//New Code
 X509Store store2= new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "CA" instead of "CertificateAuthority" for intermediate CA store.
In MSDN, it only lists the enumeration of store name, but they are not truly the right string for you to pass in.
One way to find out the right store name string is to open a store with StoreName enumeration first, and then check the store.Name value.